# NSString as float in CoreData predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have CoreData Table with NSString field. But in the filter I need to be interpreted as float.

**fieldName.floatValue** does not give the correct result. If any way to do this without changing the field type in the table ?

**Edit:**

**Data is:**

```
company = "CompanyName";
date = "2016-01-17";
value = "379.76";
```

**My predicate**

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"value.floatValue > 2000"];
```

But value 379.76 enters the result. Using **value.floatValue** all the same values are compared as strings.

TNX

Comment: Does the string field include the value as a number, i.e. "3.1415". Then convert the string to float.
You need to fix your question and give more details, so that other people can understand.

Comment: yourString = @"2.1234"; 
float value = [yourString floatValue];

Comment: Why is the column a string when it should be a float?  Why is that date a string?

Comment: I need to do this in the description of the predicate. And column type as String historically formed.

Comment: I don't know what that means.  Are you using the correct data type to represent the data?

Answer (score 3):

If you know `value` is not negative, you can use this trick:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"abs:(value) > 2000"];
```

The `abs:` forces SQLite to treat the `value` attribute as a number.

Alternatively, add zero to it (which works for negative numbers):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"add:to:(value,0) > 2000"];
```

Comment: Interesting, though this wouldn't work if he has negative numbers and wants to account for them. Does any other function force SQLite to treat the attribute as a number? Maybe `round` or something that would have a lesser impact on the results.

Comment: I don't know of any others that would work.  I guess you could handle negative numbers by a separate clause in the predicate.  @EmilioPelaez

Comment: You are right, he could use that predicate to get all the entities where value is greater than 2000, then filter to make sure the value doesn't start with `-` to avoid getting negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change String type to Number, this is the easiest way.
You can use this predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id  _Nonnull evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings) {
    return [[evaluatedObject value] floatValue] > 2000;  // Change id to your Class
}];
```

But this predicate can not be used with CoreData. So you should store the fetch result to an array, then use this predicate with it.

Comment: Thanks to all. The main idea of the decision that I have to filter the fetch request resulting array

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try with this. 
// '>' will apply when 'value' is number. So, I first put your values in an array. Only then, I can apply the predicate.

NSString *company = @"CompanyName";
NSString *date = @"2016-01-17";
NSString *value = @"379.76";

NSArray *dataArray = @[@(value.floatValue),@(379.76),@(379),@(200)];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self > %f",200.0];
NSArray *array = [dataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
//output:@(379.76),@(379.76),@(379)
```

Comment: Tnx, Jamil. I'll try to do it. Tnx You again

Comment: in core data you 'value' should be number to avoid conversion from NSString to NSNumber

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"value > 2000"];
```

Comment: MS, tnx. Good luck. But this would lead to compare strings